# JavaFX - Disable Tab when invalid data entered in TableView

Tags: validation, tabs, tableview, javafx-8

I have a TabPane where users enter/edit data on each tab and can freely switch between tabs without having to save changes before switching to a new tab. One tab has a TableView, and I'd like to prevent users from leaving that tab if they enter invalid data. My original approach was along the same lines as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22772364/3050379), which does not quite work - the tab is not reliably changed back. I liked James_D's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22774078/3050379) and tried to implement something similar. However, most of the time the data being entered into a table is optional, so disabling other tabs until a user enters data is not an option.

What I ultimately did was extend TableColumn to add a BooleanProperty 'invalid' which I then bind to Tab's disableProperty. In that column's commit event, I validate the new value and, if it doesn't pass, set invalid = true, which disables the appropriate tab. This also does not quite work. I have custom table cells that commit edits on loss of focus. If focus is lost to clicking a different tab, the commit event is too late - the tab is first selected, then disabled. I've been wracking my brain for a workaround, but am out of ideas. If anyone has any suggestions, I would really appreciate it!

Short example (clear out any last name and click Tab 2):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TabPaneTableTest extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
    ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    table.setEditable(true);

    MyTableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new MyTableColumn<>("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));
    MyTableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new MyTableColumn<>("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

    Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>> cellFactory = (TableColumn<Person, String> p) -> new MyEditingCell<Person>();

    firstNameCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
    lastNameCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);

    firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<Person, String> event) -> {
      event.getRowValue().setFirstName(event.getNewValue());
    });
    lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<Person, String> event) -> {
      if(event.getNewValue().trim().isEmpty()) {
        new Alert(AlertType.ERROR, "Last name must be filled out!", ButtonType.OK).showAndWait();
        lastNameCol.setInvalid(true);
      }
      else {
        event.getRowValue().setLastName(event.getNewValue());
        lastNameCol.setInvalid(false);
      }
    });

    table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);
    table.setItems(data);
    data.add(new Person("Luke", "Skywalker"));
    data.add(new Person("Han", "Solo"));
    data.add(new Person("R2", "D2"));

    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
    Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab 1");
    tab1.setClosable(false);
    tab1.setContent(table);

    Tab tab2 = new Tab("Tab 2");
    tab2.setClosable(false);
    tab2.disableProperty().bind(lastNameCol.invalidProperty());
    tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2);

    Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane, 400, 200);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Tab Pane Table Validation Test");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public class MyEditingCell<S> extends TableCell<S, String> {
    private TextField editingField;

    private void createEditingField() {
      editingField = new TextField(getString());
      editingField.focusedProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if(!newValue) {
          commitEdit(editingField.getText());
        }
      });
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
      super.startEdit();
      createEditingField();
      setText(null);
      setGraphic(editingField);
      Platform.runLater(() -> {
        editingField.requestFocus();
        editingField.selectAll();
      });
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
      super.cancelEdit();
      setText((String)getItem());
      setGraphic(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
      super.updateItem(item, empty);

      if(empty) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
      }
      else {
        if(isEditing()) {
          if(editingField != null) {
            editingField.setText(getString());
          }
          setText(null);
          setGraphic(editingField);
        }
        else {
          setText(getString());
          setGraphic(null);
        }
      }
    }

    private String getString() {
      return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
  }

  public class MyTableColumn<S, T> extends TableColumn<S, T> {
    private BooleanProperty invalid = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    public MyTableColumn(String header) {
      super(header);
      setEditable(true);
    }

    public BooleanProperty invalidProperty() {
      return invalid;
    }

    public boolean getInvalid() {
      return invalid.get();
    }

    public void setInvalid(boolean value) {
      invalid.set(value);
    }
  }

  public class Person {

    private StringProperty firstName;
    private StringProperty lastName;

    public Person(String first, String last) {
      firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName", first);
      lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName", last);
    }

    public void setFirstName(String value) {
      firstNameProperty().set(value);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
      return firstNameProperty().get();
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
      if(firstName == null)
        firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName", "First");
      return firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String value) {
      lastNameProperty().set(value);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
      return lastNameProperty().get();
    }

    public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
      if(lastName == null)
        lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName", "Last");
      return lastName;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create your observable list with an extractor, for example:

```
ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(person -> 
    new Observable[] { person.lastNameProperty() });
```

then the list will fire update notifications any time any of the specified properties change in any of the elements (in this case, any time the `lastName` changes on anything in the list).

So now you can create a binding for `invalid`:

```
BooleanBinding invalid = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
    () -> data.stream().anyMatch(person -> person.getLastName().isEmpty()),
    data);
```

And then you can just observe that binding:

```
invalid.addListener((obs, wasInvalid, isNowInvalid) -> {
    if (isNowInvalid) {
        // show alert, etc...
    }
});
```

or disable a node by binding to it:

```
someNode.disableProperty().bind(invalid);
```

You could similarly bind this `invalid` property in your `TableColumn` subclass (if you still need that) to this binding.